# Подскажите php-скрипт бэкапа mysql базы

Tags: php, mysql

Привет! Нужен скрипт который выполнялся бы по крону и делал бэкап 2х БД и высылал мне его на почтовый ящик. Видел что-то подобное, но не помню автора скрипта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [backup2mail](http://www.backup2mail.com/)
- [mysqldumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/)